# Initial Value and Limits

Tags: calculus

The differential equation below describes the velocity of an object in free fall with a viscous drag force. Solve the initial value problem and then find the limit $lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} v(t)$.

$$m\frac{dv}{dt}=-mg-kv, v(0)=v_0$$

Any help on this problem would be very helpful as I am stuck.

Comment: This is an example of what is known as a separable differential equation.

Comment: How do you solve a separable differential equation? We have not gone over them yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Let me try to make is as simple as possible.*

Considering the differnetial equation $$m\frac{dv}{dt}=-mg-kv\tag 1$$ make a change of variable $$mg+kv=x\implies v=\frac{x-mg }{k}\implies \frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{1}{k}\frac{dx}{dt}$$ Replacing in $(1)$, this gives $$\frac{m}{k}\frac{dx}{dt}=-x\tag 2\implies \frac{dx}{x}=-\frac{k}{m}\,dt$$ Integrating both sides $$\log(x)=-\frac{k}{m}t+C_1\implies x=C_2\exp\left(-\frac{k}{m}t\right)\tag 3$$ Back to $v$ $$mg+kv=C_2\exp\left(-\frac{k}{m}t\right)\implies v=C_3\exp\left(-\frac{k}{m}t\right)-\frac {mg}k\tag 4$$ Now, apply the condition $$v_0=C_3-\frac {mg}k\implies C_3=v_0+\frac {mg}k \tag 5$$ which finally gives $$v=\left(v_0+\frac {mg}k\right)\exp\left(-\frac{k}{m}t\right)-\frac {mg}k\tag 6$$ As you see, we can do it using a little of algebra and simple integration.